# Problem with storing Mapbox-TOKEN on shinyapps.io

Tags: r, mapbox, shinyapps

ive something pretty weird and I don't know how to get my head around.

I just want to make an leaflet app accessible via shiny apps. It uses mapbox as a basemap.

No matter how I turn it, I get an error and the app crashes. This happens most of the time as soon as two users want to use the app. The logs confuse me.

I need some assistance on how to deploy and store tokens on shinyapp, especially the mapbox one and making it accessible for two instances. I have google API Tokens inside and they work without any problems.

On my computer the script works nicely.

If I Do

```
mb_access_token("MAPBOX_TOKEN", install = TRUE)
  readRenviron("~/.Renviron")
```

I get an app shutdown with the logs

```
Warning: Error in : A MAPBOX_PUBLIC_TOKEN already exists. You can overwrite it with the argument overwrite=TRUE
```

when I change my code to `overwrite = TRUE` instead, I get the Error

`Error: Mapbox Token already exists`

The whole code is shown here:

```
library(leaflet)
library(mapboxapi)
library(mapview)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(remotes)
library(dplyr)
library(googleway)
library(tidyverse)
library(pagedown)

dashboard <- dashboardPage(
  skin = "black",
  dashboardHeader(title = "Analytics Tool"),
  

  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Kartengrundlage", tabName = "kgl"),
      menuItem("Erreichbarkeit", tabName = "iso")
    )
    ),
  
  dashboardBody(
    tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: calc(100vh - 80px) !important;}"),
    tabItems(
    # First tab content
    tabItem(tabName = "kgl",
    fluidRow(box(width = 12, textInput("ort", "Ort", "TurmstraBe 20, 10551"))),
    fluidRow(box(width = 12, height = 780, solidHeader = TRUE, leaflet::leafletOutput(outputId = "mymap", height = 720), title = "Map"),
    fluidRow(box(width = 12, solidHeader = TRUE, title = downloadButton("exportmaphtml","Export as HTML"),downloadButton("exportmappdf","Export as pdf"), downloadButton("exportmappng","Export as jpeg"))
             ))),
    
    
    # Second tab content
    tabItem(tabName = "iso",
    fluidRow(
              ))
    
    ))
  )


db_server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  output$exportmappdf <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "map.pdf",
    content = function(file) {
      
      mapshot(map$dat, url = "/map.html", remove_controls = c("zoomControl", "layersControl", "homeButton", "scaleBar",
                                                           "drawToolbar", "easyButton", "control"))
      
      
      chrome_print("map.html", output = "map.pdf" )
      
      file.copy("map.pdf", file)
    }
  ) 
  
  output$exportmaphtml <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "map.html",
    content = function(file) {
      
      mapshot(map$dat, url = paste0(getwd(), "/map.html"), remove_controls = c("zoomControl", "layersControl", "homeButton", "scaleBar",
                                                                               "drawToolbar", "easyButton", "control"))
      
      file.copy(paste0(getwd(), "/map.html"), file)
    }
  )  
  
  
  output$exportmappng <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "map.png",
    content = function(file) {
      
      mapshot(map$dat, url = "map.html", remove_controls = c("zoomControl", "layersControl", "homeButton", "scaleBar",
                                                             "drawToolbar", "easyButton", "control"))
      
      chrome_print("map.html", output = "map.png", format = "png")
      
      file.copy(paste0(getwd(), "/map.png"), file)
    }
  ) 
  
  
  Ort_geocode <- reactive({
    
    Places <-
      google_geocode(
        address = input$ort,     #'TurmstraBe 20, 10551',#
        simplify = TRUE,
        set_key("GOOGLE_KEY"))
    
    keeps2 <- c("geometry", "formatted_address", "place_id")
    Location_Clean = Places$results[keeps2]
    Location_Clean_2 <- Location_Clean %>% 
      unnest(geometry) %>% 
      unnest(location) %>%
      subset(select = c("lat", "lng")) 
    
    return(Location_Clean_2)
    
  })

  
  set_key( "GOOGLE_KEY" )
  mb_access_token("MAPBOX_TOKEN", install = TRUE)
  readRenviron("~/.Renviron")


   map <- reactiveValues(dat = 0)
  
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    
    map$dat <-leaflet(Ort_geocode()) %>%
      setView(Ort_geocode()$lng, Ort_geocode()$lat, zoom = 12) %>%
      addMapboxTiles(style_id = "xyz",
                     username = "xyz") %>%
      addMarkers(lat= Ort_geocode()$lat, lng= Ort_geocode()$lng, group = "Standort") %>%
    addLayersControl(
      overlayGroups = c("Standort"),
      options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = TRUE))
    
  })
  }
    
shinyApp (ui = dashboard , server = db_server)
```

Best regards,
Sebastian